# Is "assembly loading" just another term of "reading metadata tables"?

Tags: c#, .net

This [MSDN documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo?view=net-5.0) says:

> ... you can manipulate Type objects without necessarily requiring the runtime to load the assembly they reference.

So I write a simple application to verify an assembly won't be loaded when we only create a type object:

```
using System;
using MyLibrary;

// Main.exe
class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      Type t = typeof(Demo);
      var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();  // you can verify that MyLibrary.dll is loaded
      ...
   }
}
```

and the referenced type `Demo` is in an external assembly (MyLibrary.dll):

```
//MyLibrary.dll
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class Demo { ... }
}
```

We can see that `MyLibrary.dll` is still loaded by the CLR.

But what I think assembly loading is not nesseary here, here is my grounds:

When we compile `Main.exe` and `MyLibrary.dll`, the csc compiler detects that `Demo` will be used in the application, so the compiler emit a assembly reference record into the `Main.exe`'s AssemblyRef table and TypeRef table. The former record shows that `MyLibrary.dll` is the referenced assembly and the latter record shows that the referenced type is `Demo`.

So after the program is compiled and about to run, CLR should be smart enough to read the TypeRef table of `Main.exe` itself to know that `Demo` is the referenced type, since Type object is a lightweight obejct compared to TypeInfo object, the CLR doesn't need to read the metadata tables of `MyLibrary.dll`, so if assembly loading" just another term of "reading metadata tables", then CLR shouldn't load `MyLibrary.dll`.

But as you can see CLR still loads `MyLibrary.dll`, so does it mean that "assembly loading" does more than "reading metadata tables"?

Comment: `Assembly.Load`... *loads an assembly*; an assembly is more than metadata tables; it contains the modules, and the IL for all the code - *and* the metadata tables. To create a `Type` object via `typeof`, the runtime wants to know that all the pieces it is going to need later are around, so it loads the assembly fully (although it doesn't "JIT" everything until it is needed).

Comment: @Marc Gravell thanks for your answer. Could you provide me a concrete example when CLR won't load an assembly when accessing a type object from the assembly?